# Por que "centro-oeste" e não "centro-leste"?

Tags: significado, origem

No Brasil "centro-oeste" se refere à região central do país, que coincide um pouco com "Mid-West" nos EUA, embora nos EUA não seja exatamente a região central, mas mais centro-norte.

Mas por que "oeste" e não "leste"? Qual a referência para se usar "oeste"? O Atlântico? Europa? É um tipo de  orientação eurocêntrica como quase tudo na cultura ocidental?

E a semelhança com "Mid-West" nos EUA é apenas coincidência?

Em outros países lusófonos como eles interpretam "centro-oeste"? A exemplo Angola que tem sua costa à oeste e o interior a leste? Uma região central em Angola seria "centro-leste"?

Comment: Para a mim a referência é o próprio Brasil. Sem eu saber nada, se me mostrassem o mapa das atuais regiões do Brasil e me pedissem para indicar o Centro-Oeste, eu indicá-lo-ia corretamente; se me pedissem para indicar o Centro-Leste (sei que não existe) eu indicaria o atual Sudeste, que fica mais ou menos a leste do Centro-Oeste. Há alguma arbitrariedade e acidentes da evolução histórica nestes nomes. Se me pedissem para dar eu nomes às atuais regiões, eu sugeria Centro, Norte, Nordeste, Leste e Sul. Na verdade, em 1913 o atual Centro-Oeste + Rondónia era simplesmente o "Centro" >>

Comment: @Jacinto Para mim há uma diferença entre uma parte *do oeste* que é bastante central e uma parte *do centro* que é bastante ocidental. Nos EUA o “Midwest” é a parte “mais próxima” (ou seja, perto do mar Atlântico) *do oeste*, enquanto o “Far West” é a parte mais distante *do oeste*. A região dos EUA faz a parte central *do oeste*, mas a região do Brasil faz a parte ocidental *do centro*.

Comment: @tchrist, acho que você quis dizer "leste" em "mais próxima do oeste (Atlântico)" e a "parte mais distante do oeste (Farwest)", que neste último seria "oeste distante". A outra coisa que questiono é se "central do oeste" e "ocidental do centro" não são de certa forma a mesma coisa.

Comment: @tchrist, Luciano, Na prática, o que determina as regiões identificadas por “centro do oeste” e “oeste do centro”, e se coincidem ou não, é a geografia e história. São elas que determinam se o centro fica entre sul e norte (Portugal, Chile, continente americano), entre leste e oeste (Java) ou se é um miolo rodeado por outras regiões de quase todos os lados (África, Ásia, Brasil na perspetiva de 1913). Em Portugal, o centro litoral e o litoral centro (o litoral inclui toda a faixa ocidental) coincidem, >>

Comment: >> enquanto o “Oeste” é um pequena região a norte-noroeste de Lisboa, que, quando muito, ocupa o extremo sul do oeste do centro. Nos EUA se houvesse um Centro do Canadá ao Golfo do México (central time, imagina que os EUA tinham começado no vale do Mississippi e se tinham expandido daí para leste e oeste, e não tinha havido a questão da escravatura e guerra civil para pôr o Texas, mas não o Arizona ou Novo México, no Sul), o centro do oeste ficaria fora do Centro, e o oeste do Centro ficaria a leste do Oeste.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu ia adicionar uma resposta quando vi teu primeiro comentário, que essencialmente diz tudo que eu pretendia dizer. Que tal postá-lo em formato de resposta?

Comment: @stafusa, eu não vou responder; o meu comentário foi um bocado na perspetiva, "onde é que está a dúvida?". Mas tu estás à vontade para responder e aproveitar/adaptar o que quiseres dos meus comentários.

Answer (score 1):

A referência é o centro do próprio país, e então toma-se a rosa dos ventos na posição padrão e com isso "leste/oeste" são apenas outras palavras para "direita/esquerda", e similarmente para "norte/sul".

Há uma certa arbitrariedade em como uma dada região acaba sendo chamada, até porque há muitas possibilidades e, assim, até mais que a geografia, a história e a política acabam muitas vezes definindo esses nomes.

Tanto é assim, que várias definições já foram usadas no Brasil. Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regi%C3%B5es_do_Brasil#Hist%C3%B3ria), as divisões de 1913, 1938, 1942 e 1969 (atual) são (no sentido horário começando no *topo à esquerda* - ou *noroeste* ;-)) as seguintes:

[image]
[image]
 <sub>1: Centro-oeste, 2: Nordeste, 3: Norte, 4: Sudeste, 5: Sul.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

No meu entendimento os motivos são históricos, devido à forma de colonização e exploração do país, partindo do litoral em direção ao oeste. Exatamente pelo mesmo motivo que o Velho Oeste americano não é Velho Leste. Afinal, ao leste temos apenas o oceano Atlântico, e não territórios.

Coordenadas geográficas, por definição, são uma convenção, uma vez que o universo não possui Norte ou Sul. Estas convenções normalmente são relacionadas a motivos históricos e remontam à Europa e a forma de colonização dos continentes. Assim, o "velho oeste" americano ou o "centro oeste" brasileiro são oeste em relação à Europa, aonde fica o meridiano de GreenWich, que é o marco zero e referência da latitude.

Portanto, normalmente entendemos como "oeste" as coordenadas que estão entre 0 e 180 graus de latitude oeste em relação ao meridiano de GreenWich.

No caso específico do Brasil, em grande parte do território a região Oeste está coberta por florestas pouco povoadas, e a referência acaba sendo as cidades do Leste, que foram inicialmente colonizadas. Assim que os portugueses se estabeleceram no Brasil, firmaram as primeiras colônias no litoral, e lentamente avançaram em direção à região central.